# Convert int variable value to char array value in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I tried it my way, want to know where am i going wrong and to know how to replace int variable value to one of the index of char array?

```
string time = "07:05:45PM";
string result = string.Empty;
char[] time_Char = time.ToCharArray();
int first_Char = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(time_Char[0]) + 1;
int second_Char = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(time_Char[1]) + 2;

time_Char[0] = Convert.ToChar(first_Char);
time_Char[1] = Convert.ToChar(second_Char);

for (int i = 0; i < time_Char.Length; i++)
{
 result += time_Char[i];
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output -** 
       :05:45PM

**Expected Output -**
19:05:45PM

Comment: `Convert.ToChar(first_Char)` turns a integer to a character *with the corresponding character code*, not one that has the equivalent numeral face-value. This the same reason as to why `Char.GetNumericValue` must be used instead of `Convert.ToInt32`: so *what is the 'opposite' of `Char.GetNumericValue`*?

Comment: Are you just trying to convert a 12 hour time into 24 hour time?  Because there are _way_ easier ways of doing this...

Comment: manipulate DateTimes using the DateTime functions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to turn a 12 hour time into a 24 hour time?  It is not super clear from your question because obviously `AM/PM` are irrelevant when you are dealing with 24 time...

However if this is what you are trying to do there are *way* easier ways of doing this.  You should just parse your input string into a new `DateTime` object, then you can output that date/time using [custom formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) when calling `.ToString()`:

```
string time = "07:05:45PM";

DateTime output;
if(DateTime.TryParse(time, out output))
{
    Console.WriteLine(output.ToString("HH:mm:sstt"));
}
```

This would output: `19:05:45PM`

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5GaXNq)

Comment: Yeah,but is there any way to replace a index of character array with int value?

Comment: @NaveenKumar Why do you want to do this?  It does not make sense given the context indicated in your question